# Why dont I get a warning in visual studio 2008 when checking out a page?

Tags: visual-studio

In vs 1.1 i get a warning message when trying to check out a page.But in vs 2008,i dont get a warning.What can be problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like that by default - a bad default setting if there ever was one.

Go to: Tools / Options / Source Control / Environment

Under Checked-in Items, set to "Prompt for Check Out"

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need warning when you are performing an activity?

Check the Output window - it will show you what has been checked out.

---

Warning - you are commenting on an answer!

Comment: I just wondered.I dont need warning but in 1.1 it gives warning.

Answer (score 0):

Go to visual studio options under source control. Its an option that might have become switched off.